# Multiple apps, one database heroku rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

A friend and I have an idea to create multiple apps via heroku using Postgres.

Is there away we can tie in all the databases into one singular database by either pushing each one individually or just having them all indexed?

Comment: Just point all your apps to the same database

Comment: I thought this would work but there will also be the same model names as well. Will they override each other?

Comment: Why would you want to use the same database, again? If you're being cheapskates, just name your models differently. If there's actual reason to use the same database, models having the same names is actually a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use `heroku config` in the app with the provisioned database to get the connection string. Then use `heroku config:set PG_URL=3829w:8eh8fe78hfd@ffeiwfafdsa.amazonaws.com/8fdHUfdsa` to set the database in the other app. Now both apps will use the same database. They won't overwrite each other, but they will write to the same DB.

Comment: Now, there _will_ be problems if two (or more) apps use a model (`User`, for example) with different sets of fields, validations, etc. Data from one app will likely break the others. Models/tables should be prefixed, if this is a multi-tenancy scenario. If data is meant to be shared, then they'll figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple schemas, which will namespace the tables per-schema and avoid any name conflicts between each app's models.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#multiple-schemas

> The most common use case for using multiple schemas in a database is building a software-as-a-service application wherein each customer has their own schema.

The flipside (as the link points out) is that multiple schemas can significantly reduce performance. You're also sharing connection limits, cache and disk space between apps. This might not be a problem depending on your usage, but just be aware of it.

Further reading:

- `CREATE SCHEMA` docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createschema.html
- Set `schema_search_path` in `database.yml` in each app to your individual schemas: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html